# Equation for Interrupted Times Series Analysis with Multiple Intervention with Control Series

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis, control-group

I have used STATA to conduct an ITSA but am having trouble writing the equation for it.

Period A: 2005-2010
Intervention 1
Period B: 2011-2015
Intervention 2
Period C: 2016-2020

I understand the following equation when conducting ITSA for a single intervention with a control series: Yt=β0+β1T+β2Xt+β3TXt+β4Z+β5ZT+β6ZXt+β7ZXtT.

My question is how do I write one for multiple interventions (at least 2) with a control series. Or is the equation above valid because the model compares Period A to Period B and Period B to Period C separately?

Thank you in advance.